# pipreqs not including all libraries used in requirements.txt

Tags: python, requirements.txt

In Anaconda Prompt on Windows 10, I navigated into the directory of my project and type `pipreqs`, which creates a `requirements.txt` file. However, it does not include all of the libraries I import in my project.

In my project, I have two python scripts. Scraper.py has:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pandas as pd
```

Bot.py has:

```
import praw
import time
import pandas as pd
import os.path
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import config
```

The requirements.txt file just includes:

```
pandas==1.1.3
requests==2.24.0
praw==7.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
```

Note: I am not using a virtual env and typing `pipreqs` in the regular command prompt returns the following error:

```
'pipreqs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all not included modules are Python Standard Library modules! They already come with Python.